# UI fails to display contents after switching from activities to Fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I have developed a messaging feature using Layer(atlas for UI) SDK. 
I am able to see the conversation list in the UI if the implementation is w.r.t activities but after switching to fragments from activities, the UI appears empty. The switch to fragment is required because the app has navigation tabs implemented using ViewPager concept and messaging is one of the tab.
Below are the files I have, Please let me know if I am missing anything while using fragments.

### Fragment implementation

```
public class ConversationListFragment extends Fragment {
    private AtlasConversationsRecyclerView mConversationsList;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (App.routeLogin(getActivity())) {
            if (!getActivity().isFinishing()) getActivity().finish();
        }
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_conversations_list, container, false);
        mConversationsList = (AtlasConversationsRecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.conversations_list);
        initializeConversationList();

        return v;
    }

    private void initializeConversationList() {
        // Atlas methods
        mConversationsList.init(getLayerClient(), getParticipantProvider(), getPicasso())
                .setInitialHistoricMessagesToFetch(20)
                .setOnConversationClickListener(new AtlasConversationsAdapter.OnConversationClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onConversationClick(AtlasConversationsAdapter adapter, Conversation conversation) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), MessagesListActivity.class);
                        if (Log.isLoggable(Log.VERBOSE)) {
                            Log.v("Launching MessagesListActivity with existing conversation ID: " + conversation.getId());
                        }
                        intent.putExtra(PushNotificationReceiver.LAYER_CONVERSATION_KEY, conversation.getId());
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public boolean onConversationLongClick(AtlasConversationsAdapter adapter, Conversation conversation) {
                        return false;
                    }
                })
                .setOnConversationSwipeListener(new SwipeableItem.OnSwipeListener<Conversation>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSwipe(final Conversation conversation, int direction) {
                        new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext())
                                .setMessage(R.string.alert_message_delete_conversation)
                                .setNegativeButton(R.string.alert_button_cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                        // TODO: simply update this one conversation
                                        mConversationsList.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
                                        dialog.dismiss();
                                    }
                                })
                                .setPositiveButton(R.string.alert_button_delete, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                        conversation.delete(LayerClient.DeletionMode.ALL_PARTICIPANTS);
                                    }
                                }).show();
                    }
                });

        App.getParticipantProvider().registerParticipantListener((AtlasConversationsAdapter) mConversationsList.getAdapter());

    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        android.util.Log.i("###", "BaseFragment-onResume");
        super.onResume();
        LayerClient client = App.getLayerClient();
        if (client == null) return;
        if (client.isAuthenticated()) {
            client.connect();
        } else {
            client.authenticate();
        }
    }

    protected LayerClient getLayerClient() {
        return App.getLayerClient();
    }

    protected ParticipantProvider getParticipantProvider() {
        return App.getParticipantProvider();
    }

    protected Picasso getPicasso() {
        return App.getPicasso();
    }
```

### Activity Implementation

```
public class ConversationsListActivity extends BaseActivity {

    private AtlasConversationsRecyclerView mConversationsList;

    public ConversationsListActivity() {
        super(R.layout.activity_conversations_list, R.menu.menu_conversations_list, R.string.title_conversations_list, false);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (App.routeLogin(this)) {
            if (!isFinishing()) finish();
            return;
        }

        mConversationsList = (AtlasConversationsRecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.conversations_list);

        // Atlas methods
        mConversationsList.init(getLayerClient(), getParticipantProvider(), getPicasso())
                .setInitialHistoricMessagesToFetch(20)
                .setOnConversationClickListener(new AtlasConversationsAdapter.OnConversationClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onConversationClick(AtlasConversationsAdapter adapter, Conversation conversation) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(ConversationsListActivity.this, MessagesListActivity.class);
                        if (Log.isLoggable(Log.VERBOSE)) {
                            Log.v("Launching MessagesListActivity with existing conversation ID: " + conversation.getId());
                        }
                        intent.putExtra(PushNotificationReceiver.LAYER_CONVERSATION_KEY, conversation.getId());
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public boolean onConversationLongClick(AtlasConversationsAdapter adapter, Conversation conversation) {
                        return false;
                    }
                })
                .setOnConversationSwipeListener(new SwipeableItem.OnSwipeListener<Conversation>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSwipe(final Conversation conversation, int direction) {
                        new AlertDialog.Builder(ConversationsListActivity.this)
                                .setMessage(R.string.alert_message_delete_conversation)
                                .setNegativeButton(R.string.alert_button_cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                        // TODO: simply update this one conversation
                                        mConversationsList.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
                                        dialog.dismiss();
                                    }
                                })
                                .setPositiveButton(R.string.alert_button_delete, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                        conversation.delete(LayerClient.DeletionMode.ALL_PARTICIPANTS);
                                    }
                                }).show();
                    }
                });

        App.getParticipantProvider().registerParticipantListener((AtlasConversationsAdapter) mConversationsList.getAdapter());

        findViewById(R.id.floating_action_button)
                .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        startActivity(new Intent(ConversationsListActivity.this, MessagesListActivity.class));
                    }
                });
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_settings:
                return true;

            case R.id.action_sendlogs:
                LayerClient.sendLogs(getLayerClient(), this);
                return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

### Base Activity

```
public abstract class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private final int mLayoutResId;
    private final int mMenuResId;
    private final int mMenuTitleResId;
    private final boolean mMenuBackEnabled;

    public BaseActivity(int layoutResId, int menuResId, int menuTitleResId, boolean menuBackEnabled) {
        mLayoutResId = layoutResId;
        mMenuResId = menuResId;
        mMenuTitleResId = menuTitleResId;
        mMenuBackEnabled = menuBackEnabled;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(mLayoutResId);

        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        if (actionBar == null) return;
        if (mMenuBackEnabled) actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setTitle(mMenuTitleResId);
    }

    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        if (actionBar == null) {
            super.setTitle(title);
        } else {
            actionBar.setTitle(title);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setTitle(int titleId) {
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        if (actionBar == null) {
            super.setTitle(titleId);
        } else {
            actionBar.setTitle(titleId);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        Log.i("###","BaseActivity-onResume");
        super.onResume();
        LayerClient client = App.getLayerClient();
        if (client == null) return;
        if (client.isAuthenticated()) {
            client.connect();
        } else {
            client.authenticate();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(mMenuResId, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
            // Menu "Navigate Up" acts like hardware back button
            onBackPressed();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    protected LayerClient getLayerClient() {
        return App.getLayerClient();
    }

    protected ParticipantProvider getParticipantProvider() {
        return App.getParticipantProvider();
    }

    protected Picasso getPicasso() {
        return App.getPicasso();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you getting any crashes ?

Comment: @Shadab Ansari, I do see the below crash only while debugging but NO crash while run. java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'boolean android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.mAddToBackStack' on a null object reference
                                                                               at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:740)

Comment: so while running without debugging , what issue exactly do you observe ?

Comment: While running without debugging , I just see an empty screen.

Comment: Can you paste the xml where you have ViewPager?

Answer (score 1):

After a good debug session, figured out that Layer-Atlas SDK has a condition to refresh on resume.

```
public AtlasMessagesRecyclerView refresh() {
    if (mAdapter != null) mAdapter.refresh();
    return this;
}
```

so by just calling the refresh method from ConversationListFragment onResume, solved the issue.

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    LayerClient client = App.getLayerClient();
    if (client == null) return;
    if (client.isAuthenticated()) {
        client.connect();
    } else {
        client.authenticate();
    }
    mConversationsList.refresh();
}
```